# I want to redirect anyHOST.anyTLD to www.anyHOST.anyTLD

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to find a generic enough modrewrite rule that will acomplish following:

- Redirect anyHost.anyTld to www.anyHost.anyTld
- Not mess with any other subdomains, for examle other.anyHost.anyTLD should be left alone

Can you help?
Does this slow down server too much?

Answer (score 2):

Zach's answer will not work with subdomains like `forum.example.com`, the next rules checks whether the host equals `example.com`. If it does, it will be redirected to `www.example.com`. No rules will be processed after this one (`L` = Last).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This does not cause a server slowdown, but if you really want to get every single performance bit out of it, you could create a virtual host with domain `example.com` with a redirect rule:

```
NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
# other hosts here
```

[Virtual Hosts documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use something like this:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*)$

RewriteRule (.*) $1/$2 [NC]

Let me know how it turns out, I don't have access to an Apache machine to test it right now :)